# How can I send http post request on python with protobuf text as params?

Tags: python-3.x, httprequest, protocol-buffers

I want to send http request using `protobuf` as params on python. I copied the `protobuf` data from charles proxy (web debugging proxy tool).
the `protobuf` text request data was:`1 { 1: "2345654456765" }` 
i tried this but not working:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://api.website.com/version/auth/login?locale=en',data={1:{1:'2345654456765'}},headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4181.9 Safari/537.36','platform': 'web',})
print(r.content)
```

I have no idea of how can I put this as a param. I always worked with `json` data. Is there anyone who knows the solution?

Comment: Please add some more information about that text data because usually the protobuf messages are serialized in binary format. That looks like it's binary data.

Comment: yes this is binary data, i didn't get anything else on the debugger.